# Set enumeration level explicitly

Tags: lists, environments, enumerate

I have the need for a custom list environment at the outermost level, defined as follows:

```
\newboolean{odd}
\setboolean{odd}{true}
\usepackage{environ}
\newcounter{exnum}[section]% Exercise counter (within section)
\NewEnviron{solution}{% Solution
   \stepcounter{exnum}%
   \ifthenelse{\isodd{\theexnum}}% Condition on oddness
      {\item \BODY}% Print odd answer
      {\ifthenelse{\boolean{odd}}{}{\item \BODY}}% Print odd
}
\newenvironment{outerlist}%
    {\begin{list}%
        {{\bfseries\arabic{exnum}.}}{}}%
    {\end{list}}%
```

The point of all of this is to be able to set the `odd` boolean and change whether all items, or just the odd-numbered items, are output.

This all works fine, except that this list environment, `outerlist`, does not increment the enumeration level. As a result, inner enumerations start at level 1. This is not consistent with the visual appearance (`outerlist` obviously looks like an outer enumeration in the output), and is confusing to the maintainer (I confused myself a couple of times :)

Can I tell LaTeX to start with enumeration level 2? Or is there a better way to write the above so as to get the behavior I want?

Edit: Per request, here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcounter{itemnum}
\NewEnviron{outeritem}{% Solution
   \stepcounter{itemnum}%
   {\item \BODY}%
}

\newenvironment{outerlist}%
    {\begin{list}%
        {{\bfseries\arabic{itemnum}.}}{}}%
    {\end{list}}%

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{{\bfseries(\alph{enumi})}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{{\bfseries(\roman{enumii})}}

\begin{document}

\begin{outerlist}
\begin{outeritem}
  This level is numbered with arabic numerals, but is not really an enumerate list.
\end{outeritem}
\begin{outeritem}
  This is outer list item 2.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This looks visually to be at level 2, but LaTeX thinks of it as a level 1 enum, 
        and it is governed by $\backslash$labelenumi. I would like it to be governed by
        $\backslash$labelenumii, so that the TeX file can use level 2 definitions for 
        this list level format.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{outeritem}
\end{outerlist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use the `enumerate` environment instead of `outerlist`? Replace `itemnum` with `enumi` and omit the `\stepcounter` command since `\item` will automatically do that to `enumi`. Also, it is not necessary for `outeritem` to be an environment. It could just be a `\newcommand` that takes an argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to adjust the list depth/level. Let's see what `enumerate` does (taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\enumerate{%
  \ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@enumctr\endcsname
        {\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
```

Within the definition `\advance\@enumdepth\@ne` increases the depth/level of the enumeration. We could define

```
\newcommand{\advanceenumeratelevel}{\advance\@enumdepth\@ne}
```

and use it where needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ

\newcounter{itemnum}
\NewEnviron{outeritem}{% Solution
   \stepcounter{itemnum}%
   {\item \BODY}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\advanceenumeratelevel}{\advance\@enumdepth\@ne}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{outerlist}%
  {\begin{list}%
    {{\bfseries\arabic{itemnum}.}}{}}%
  {\end{list}}%

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{{\bfseries(\alph{enumi})}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{{\bfseries(\textit{\roman{enumii}})}}

\begin{document}

\begin{outerlist}
\begin{outeritem}
  This level is numbered with arabic numerals, but is not really an enumerate list.
\end{outeritem}
\begin{outeritem}
  This is outer list item 2.
  \advanceenumeratelevel
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This looks visually to be at level 2, but LaTeX thinks of it as a level 1 enum, 
        and it is governed by $\backslash$labelenumi. I would like it to be governed by
        $\backslash$labelenumii, so that the TeX file can use level 2 definitions for 
        this list level format.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{outeritem}
\end{outerlist}
\end{document}
```

Since I don't know the full extent of usage for `enumerate` inside your lists, you may have to consider demoting the level at the end of `outeritem`. For example, the following may be sufficient:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\advanceenumeratelevel}{\advance\@enumdepth\@ne}
\newcommand{\retractenumeratelevel}{\advance\@enumdepth\m@ne}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{outerlist}%
  {\advanceenumeratelevel%
   \begin{list}%
    {{\bfseries\arabic{itemnum}.}}{}}%
  {\end{list}%
   \retractenumeratelevel}%
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd go with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewEnviron{outeritem}{% Solution
  \item \BODY
}

\newlist{outerlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[outerlist,1]{label=\bfseries\arabic*.,resume,before=\advancedepth}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\bfseries(\roman*)}
\makeatletter
% hook into LaTeX's enumerate depth
\newcommand{\advancedepth}{\advance\@enumdepth\@ne}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{outerlist}
\begin{outeritem}
  This level is numbered with arabic numerals
\end{outeritem}
\begin{outeritem}
  This is outer list item 2.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is at level 2.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{outeritem}
\end{outerlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The printing only of even numbered items is easy to add:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{enumitem,etoolbox}

\newtoggle{printodd}
\NewEnviron{outeritem}{% Solution
  \iftoggle{printodd}
    {%
     \item \BODY
    }
    {%
     \ifnumodd{\value{outerlisti}}
       {\item\BODY}% the next item is even, print it
       {\stepcounter{outerlisti}}% the next item is odd, skip it
    }%
}

\newlist{outerlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[outerlist,1]{label=\bfseries\arabic*.,resume,before=\advancedepth}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\bfseries(\roman*)}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\advancedepth}{\advance\@enumdepth\@ne}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The toggle is initially false, only even numbered items are printed

\begin{outerlist}
\begin{outeritem}
  This level is numbered with arabic numerals
\end{outeritem}
\begin{outeritem}
  This is outer list item 2.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is at level 2.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{outeritem}
\end{outerlist}

Now we set the toggle to true, all items are printed
\toggletrue{printodd}

\begin{outerlist}
\begin{outeritem}
  This level is numbered with arabic numerals
\end{outeritem}
\begin{outeritem}
  This is outer list item 2.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is at level 2.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{outeritem}
\end{outerlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that's pretty cool. But one of the things I removed in my MWE, which is actually the reason that I implemented this odd-looking thing to begin with, is that I want the ability at runtime to emit or not emit even-numbered top-level list items by setting a switch (see the original posted TeX). Are there any hooks I can put into your answer to make that happen?

Comment: I posted a comment but forgot to tag you, so I'm doing that now.

Comment: @rogerl I added a possible way to go

Answer (score 0):

I refer to what you really wanted: just outputting odd/even items if the relevant boolean is set that way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{oodd}
\setboolean{oodd}{true}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{Item}{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{oodd}}
 {
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}}}{\item \BODY}{\refstepcounter{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}}
 }
 {\item\BODY}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{Item}
Eins
\end{Item}
\begin{Item}
Zwei
\begin{enumerate}
 \begin{Item}
 Hallo
 \end{Item}
 \begin{Item}
 Du
 \end{Item}
 \begin{Item}
 Da
 \end{Item}
 \begin{Item}
 !
 \end{Item}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Item}
\begin{Item}
Drei
\end{Item}
\begin{Item}
Vier
\end{Item}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```